# pushing and pulling to rabbitmq json in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, rabbitmq, json

I am trying to push a hash object to a rabbitmq . 
this is how i am pushing:

```
msg[:gateway] = "gat1"

    msg[:params] =  {
        :status => "2",
        :token_id => "SADF3434FG2FG",
        :mb_tranaction_id => "1235ABC",
        :random_num => "#{2*rand(155)}"
    }

    AmqpClient.instance.publish("#{RABBIT_MQ_CONFIG['ipn_queue']}", msg.to_json)
```

on the output it looks like this :

```
{\"gateway\":\"gat1\",\"params\":{\"status\":\"2\",\"token_id\":\"SADF3434FG2FG\",\"mb_tranaction_id\":\"1235ABC\",\"random_num\":\"62\"}}
```

when I am pulling, i am trying to decode it back to a hash object like so :

```
  msg = JSON.parse(msg)
  p "worker: #{msg.inspect}"
```

and the output is :

```
"worker: {\"gateway\"=>\"skrill\", \"params\"=>{\"status\"=>\"2\", \"token_id\"=>\"SADF3434FG2FG\", \"mb_tranaction_id\"=>\"1235ABC\", \"random_num\"=>\"62\"}}"
```

but when I try to access one of it's values by the key (gateway) `msg[:gateway]`
I get a blank string...

Comment: Getting a blank string means that 'msg' is effectively a hash, but the key doesn't exist. Try 'msg.keys' to get a list of all available keys, and you'll find out that none of them are symbols, but strings. So, replace :gateway with "gateway", and you're good to go!

Answer (score 2):

In JSON format, keys are represented as strings - so `msg[:gateway]` won't work - but `msg["gateway"]` would.

Alternatively, you can use Rails's `[with_indifferent_access][1]` to be able to access the hash via symbols.